# Tag followers shows different results depending on time

Tags: bug, tags, followers

I noticed what seems to me a bug as I have been observing it for few months now.

Indeed depending on the time of day hovering on JMETER tag for example shows a different number of followers.
These last weeks, I notice that it sometimes shows 165 and sometimes 177, this change can happen in few minutes.

I thought it could be a variation at first but I don't think it is as during the same day it can be 165, then 177 then back 165.

Comment: Return of [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77039/why-does-the-followers-count-change-so-dramatically?rq=1), perhaps?